# how to get image from another web server to local server when authentication is needed?

Tags: php

I'm using A REST api to connect to another company's data and i'm getting an XML with all the products data i need, this company gave me the same url with other GET parameters to get the image of this product.
for example:
the data:
http://app.somecompany.com/?productid=43554
the image:
http://app.somecompany.com/?productid=43554&type="file-IMAGE-product"

I would like to know if there is any way to get this image to my local server, when i try to use php functions like copy() or file_get_content() i'm getting an empty string, probably because of the credentials. but when i take the url and logging in to their service and than pasting the other url, 'i'm getting a view of the image.
I tried everything and i really don't know what to do, please help, i'm probably missing something.

Comment: It sounds like you want to reverse-engineer some interactions with that server.  In your web browser's debugging tools, examine the request made when you successfully download the image.  What else is on that request?  Cookies, header values, etc.  Chances are that when you *manually* do this in your browser, the browser is using something like a cookie to track your authentication.  Your code will have to replicate that functionality.  When the code makes the first request to authenticate, capture the returned cookie and include it in future requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on a project recently in which I had the exact same requirement. The REST api that I was using was protected by OAuth. I used curl to get the images.

Pass the image URL to your own PHP file, which makes a request to the image URL and pass the necessary token or username/password for authentication and then echo the image data. You will need to set the appropriate Content-Type header depending on whether the image is jpeg or png. The only problem is that since all the images will now come through your own server, the images will be loaded slowly and also it will have an additional impact on your server.

Here is a sample code that might be of some help to you:

```
$url = $_GET['pictureUrl'];

$token = '1234567890';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer $token";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$imageData = curl_exec($ch);
$imageType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: $imageType");
echo $imageData;
```